# How to access Azure app service settings/configuration in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0

I have a web app running in Azure which is currently running on .NET 5, which I'm trying to upgrade to 6. I have refactored the code to remove the `Startup.cs` file and refactored `Program.cs` to suit the new structure of .NET 6 apps. Before anybody else tells me that the old way with two files still works, yes I know, but I want to move to the new standard so that this can serve as a template for future apps, which by default when first created in VS only use the one file.

In the existing `Startup.cs` file, I have something like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

namespace MyApp.Web.Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection(Constants.AzureAdB2C))
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "https://example.com/api/query" })
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            // Other services added here
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(
                endpoints =>
                    {
                        endpoints.MapControllers();
                        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

When the `Startup` constructor is called, an `IConfiguration` instance is injected in, which I understand is done dynamically when running on DevOps to include all app settings set in the App Service -> Settings -> Configuration -> Application settings page. This all works fine at the moment.

However, the new `Program.cs` file with the .NET 6 syntax looks like this:

```
using System.Reflection;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

IConfiguration configuration;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

string appSettingsPath = Path.Combine(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
    "appsettings.json");

configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile(appSettingsPath, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection(Constants.AzureAdB2C))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "https://example.com/api/query" })
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

// Other services added here

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(
    endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });

app.Run();
```

As you can see above, there is no constructor and therefore I have no way of injecting the `IConfiguration` instance, so at the moment I'm presuming there is an `appsettings.json` file and creating it from that. This won't work when running in the Azure environment as the settings specified in the dashboard don't get added to the `appsettings.json` file, they are set as environment variables.

I can retrieve environment variables but I can't retrieve variable groups, as is the requirement in this particular case of adding `Microsoft.Identity` authentication. Is there no way of dynamically resolving/injecting the `IConfiguration` instance as before?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was over-thinking this. I figured that there is still an `IServiceCollection` being created and/or dynamically added to by the Azure app service runtime so tried removing all code that tries to create an `IConfiguration` instance and just presume that there is already one there after creating the .NET 6 `WebApplicationBuilder` instance.

Sure enough, there is. All I needed to do was reference the `builder.Configuration` instance, which already has the `IConfiguration` injected from the Azure container:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection(Constants.AzureAdB2C))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "https://example.com/api/query" })
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

// Other services added here

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(
    endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });

app.Run();
```

Just for info, if like me you have local `appsettings.json` files for running in debug or testing, I have the following methods in a helper class:

```
public static IConfiguration GetConfigurationFromAssembly(string appSettingsFileName)
{
    Assembly dataAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(
        Path.Combine(
        
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                    "MyApp.Web.Data.dll")); // Put your own project DLL containing the embedded resource here

    Stream jsonStream =
        dataAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"MyApp.Web.Data.{appSettingsFileName}");

    return new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonStream(jsonStream)
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .Build();
}

public static IConfiguration GetConfigurationFromFile(string appSettingsFileName)
{
    string appSettingsPath = Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
        appSettingsFileName);

    return new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile(appSettingsPath, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();
}
```

You can then add the returned `IConfiguration` object to the `WebApplicationBuilder` like this:

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

#if DEBUG
configuration = Configurations.GetConfigurationFromAssembly("appsettings.Development.json");

builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(configuration);
#endif

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection(Constants.AzureAdB2C))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "https://example.com/api/query" })
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```